# Ionic - How to create Image Blob from cordovaImagePicker.getPictures ImagePicker for S3

Tags: image, amazon-s3, ionic-framework, uri, blob

Using ionic,
I am trying to create an image blob from URI and have tried several codes but failed.

Here is where I implement the imagepicker in ionic:

```
  $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
    .then(function (results) {

      console.log(results[0]);
      var datablob = $scope.dataURItoBlob(results[0]);
```

technique 1 (create the blob):

```
  $scope.dataURItoBlob = function(dataURI) {

    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
      array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }

    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
      type: mimeString
    });

  }
```

technique 2 (create the blob):

```
  $scope.dataURItoBlob = function(dataURI) {

    var arr = dataURI.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});

  }
```

Both techniques does not work. Please help! thank you very much.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: You not response yet @Axil

Answer (score 0):

```
$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
            .then(function (results) {

              console.log(results[0]);
              dataURItoBlob(results[0], function(url){
                    var datablob = url;
              }, function(error){
                  console.error(error);
               })
             })

       function dataURItoBlob(path, cb, error) {
        resolveLocalFileSystemURL(path, function (fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    if (typeof cb === 'function') {
                        cb(this.result)
                    }
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            }, function (err) {
                if (typeof error === 'function') {
                    error(err)
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

> Needs to **cordova-plugin-file**